# Zebra: Printing Symbols with ZPL fails, Works with Designer

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

I'm trying to print some characters to my gk420d and hit a snag.  I can't seem to print some necessary symbols.  Some Examples: Ω, Θ (Omega, Theta).  I can pull out an old windows machine, and have installed their software, updated the firmware to the latest and Put The following in a single text box on the designer [removed, i don't have enough rep]

When I print to file from the designer, using ZEBRA 0 Font (size 10), i get the following output (copied after opening from notepad++):

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTD^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR3,3~SD25^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW194
^LL0088
^LS0
^FO32,0^GFA,02304,02304,00024,:Z64:
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:A7B6
^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

I don't understand a lot of that, it seems like the designer puts extra stuff in there different from the normal ZPL.  I have been trying to get the Ω symbol to print directly from ZPL code, but I cannot work out how.  I've tried several different combinations of the ^CI command and the hex code, but they all either print a different symbol or nothing at all.

```
^XA
^CI28
^FO10,45
^AB,16^FH
^FDOhm: _CE_A9
^FS
^XZ
```

How can I print the Ω symbol from straight zpl?

Comment: The designer determines if the character you are trying to use is included in the font you are using. If it is not there it replaces it with graphic object embedded in the label. You need to choose a font that has that character. I believe the Swiss 721 font that Zebra distributes should have those characters.  Once you have the right font use ^CI28 to be able to send that character in UTF-8. I will try to add an example later when I have a chance.

Comment: I'd suggest `^CI34,217,36` which *should* replace any `$` in your text with omega (eg `^FDOhm: $^FS`) (sorry- don't have a printer to experiment on - theory only)